# Include scrollbar in add_command, Menu button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to add a drop-down list with a scroll bar for time selection.
For example, under Hour, it will show 0 to 24 (24-hour format) and under Minute, it will show 0 to 59.

Currently, my code below exceed the window size and I was hoping I could have a scrollbar beside so the number could show until 6 or something and user have to scroll down to select if it is 20, etc.

```
popup = Tk()
popup.geometry("400x400")

var = StringVar(popup)
var.set("Hour")
menubutton = Menubutton(popup, textvariable=var, indicatoron=True, borderwidth=1, relief="raised", width=15)
menubutton.place(x=100, y=100)

sub_menu = Menu(menubutton, tearoff=False)
menubutton.configure(menu=sub_menu)
for x in range(0, 25):
    sub_menu.add_command(label=x)
#return userInput

popup.mainloop()
```

Also, is there a shorter method for a user to select the time and date beside continuously adding the menu button for different parts.

```
Day (0 to 31)        Month (Jan to Dec)        Year (Current year +/-2)

             Hour (0 to 24)        Minute (0 to 59)
```

The time and date above will have a drop-down list for the user to select.

Comment: You can consider using the `Spinbox` widget for this.

Comment: I tried using Spinbox but does it have a scrollbar for user to scroll through the days rather than clicking on the up and down button

Comment: If you prefer a scrollbar, you can try `ttk.Combobox` instead.

Comment: I decided to stick with the spinbox widget. How do I know the day name (e.g Monday, Tuesday, etc) based on the Day, Month, and Year that the user have selected?

I have used import time but could not find a way to convert it.

Comment: `datetime.datetime(month=a, day=b, year=c).strftime("%A")`.